# Definite Integration of [arccos(x)] , [.] = GIF

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to find integration of [ arccos(x) ] in its domain (-1,1)? Where [.] Is Floor function.
I tried using graph method(area) but end up getting some negative terms there.

Comment: In what domain?

Comment: Domain of arccos x. from -1 to 1

Comment: This is a step function, so you can just add up the rectangles.

Comment: Ans is Cos1 + Cos 2 + Cos 3 + 3. So its clear that this has to be solved using graph of arccos x.

Comment: @eyeballfrog i tried but i think i am missing something here. I am bad at inverse trig.

Comment: The title is misleading

Comment: @clathratus thanks for pointing it out. I have changed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos^{-1}x$ is a monotonically decreasing function, such that:

- $3\le\cos^{-1}x\le\pi$ for $-1\le x\le\cos3$
- $2\le\cos^{-1}x\le3$ for $\cos3\le x\le\cos2$
- $1\le\cos^{-1}x\le2$ for $\cos2\le x\le\cos1$
- $0\le\cos^{-1}x\le1$ for $\cos1\le x\le 1$

$I=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^1\lfloor\cos^{-1}x\rfloor dx\\=\displaystyle\int_{-1}^{\cos3}3dx+\int_{\cos3}^{\cos2}2dx+\int_{\cos2}^{\cos1}1dx+\int_{\cos1}^10dx\\=\cos1+\cos2+\cos3+3$

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a small sketch will help you

[image]

It is just a series of steps, so the integral is simple. The trick is to find the transitions, for example, to find the left-most consider $3 = \arccos(x)$, whose solution is $x = cos(3)$, so in the region $-1 \leq x \leq cos(3)$ the function is just three, and the area is

$$
\int_{-1}^{\cos(3)} \lfloor \arccos(x) \rfloor {\rm d}x = 3 [\cos(3) + 1]
$$

You can continue with the other steps, the result is

$$
\int_{-1}^{1} \lfloor \arccos(x) \rfloor {\rm d}x = \cos 1 + \cos 2 + \cos 3 + 3
$$

Comment: Thanks i just found what i was doing wrong